# gfortran compile warning, "may be used uninitialized" for obviously initialized array

Tags: memory, fortran, gfortran

My compiler has started giving me a warning on a part of my code I haven't touched while developing code...  The zarray is allocated, set to zero, then part of the array is set to rarray that is passed in.

```
SUBROUTINE advection(rbox0,rfrac,rarray,na)
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,  INTENT(IN)   :: na
  REAL, INTENT(IN)   :: rfrac 
  REAL, INTENT(IN)   :: rbox0 
  REAL, INTENT(INOUT) :: rarray(0:na)

  ! local arrays
  REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: zarray1(:),zarray2(:)


  ALLOCATE(zarray1(-4:2*na))
  zarray1(:)=0.0
  zarray1(0:na)=rarray ! zarray stores the original array
  rarray(:)=0.0
  rarray(0)=(1.0-rbox0)*zarray1(0)

  ! etc etc
```

Now with gfortran on a mac I'm getting this compile warning:

```
vectri.f90:1101:38:

 1101 |       rarray(0)=(1.0-rbox0)*zarray1(0)
      |                                      ^
Warning: 'MEM <real(kind=4)[0:]> [(real(kind=4)[0:] *)_77][4]' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

In my experience, warnings such as these are ignored at your peril, but I can't for the life of me understand why the compiler is getting upset here... I'm using

GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1) 11.3.0

EDIT: in reply to the comments below, the code was originally

```
zarray1=0.0
```

and

```
rarray=0.0
```

when the warning arose, I changed to insert `(:)` to see if it would help (it didn't :-( )

Comment: Not an answer, but in my experience gfortran is just not very good at this and generates many false positives, especially at higher optimization levels - in fact it is precisely this which stops me using `-Werror` at -O2 and higher, despite very much wanting to. But otherwise I definitely agree - ignore warnings at your peril!

Comment: @IanBush I do use `-Werror`, but in combination with `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized`. These warnings are most often just noise.

Comment: Regarding Marks's comment, see also https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this/

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  In fact the code was originally zarray1=0.0 but I changed to zarray1(:)=0.0 to see if it would help (was the same)

Comment: Hey ho .........